# starting R exit with status code 1 and no output

Tags: r, linux, ubuntu

I have just reinstalled `R` after ubuntu upgrade to 23.10 and when I try to run `R` from CLI, it is not starting. It just exit without any output. `R --version` works though.

I have tried both R version from ubuntu official repositories and cran - 0

```
$ R --version
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16) -- "Beagle Scouts"
Copyright (C) 2023 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.

$ R
$ echo $?
1
```

Comment: Starting R with `R_HOME=/usr/lib/R /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R` works.

Comment: The issue is due to `. "${R_HOME}/etc${R_ARCH}/ldpaths"` line in `/usr/bin/R` script. Once I comment it out. it works.

Comment: It is due to having `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` in  `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.